# QGIS - Joining intersecting polylines

Tags: qgis, line

How can I automatically join all lines that intersect into the same feature?

On the image below all three lines are different features, I would like them to all be the same feature, dissolve is not what i am trying to achieve since it joins all lines even if they don't intersect.

[image]

EDIT

When I run Field Calculator I get an error asking me to enter a field name? I'm also quite confused to why the Windows and macOS windows look so different?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fieldcalculator for this and update the geometry with the collected geometries of lines which intersects each other. **BUT** the geometry type of your line layer **MUST** be Multiline. So be careful with that. The expression will be this one:

```
aggregate(layer:='layername',
aggregate:='collect',
expression:= $geometry ,
filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply! I ran in to an issue. I have edited the question to include an image and with further information :)

Comment: yes you are using the field calculator from the procesing toolbox. use the fieldcalculator from the Toolbar instead!!

Comment: Thanks, i ran this now and it works for the three intersections, now i was trying to run it on all 600 features in this map and its verry slow, the application basically hangs. Any idea what i can do about it? Eventually i need to run this on a dataset that will have 5000+ features

Comment: Running it on 144 features now and QGIS is consuming a huge amount of memory, 21GB at the time of writing, my 16GB Macbook Pro is crying a bit